# Flutter Counter Application using Bloc Pattern v8.0.1 [The operator '+' isn't defined for the type 'CounterState'. Try defining the operator '+']

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc, flutter-state

I'm new to the flutter_bloc state management and I have a problem in the bloc class and state class. The operator '+' isn't defined for the type 'CounterState'.
Try defining the operator '+'.

I follow Felix Angelov's instructions here in [[Proposal] Replace mapEventToState with on in Bloc](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2526).

Here's my code

**counter_event.dart**

```
part of 'counter_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class CounterEvent extends Equatable {
  const CounterEvent();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class IncrementEvent extends CounterEvent {}

class DecrementEvent extends CounterEvent {}
```

**counter_state.dart**

```
part of 'counter_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class CounterState extends Equatable {}

class CounterInitial extends CounterState {
  final int counter;

  CounterInitial(this.counter);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [counter];
}
```

**counter_bloc.dart**

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'counter_event.dart';
part 'counter_state.dart';

class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, CounterState> {
  CounterBloc() : super(CounterInitial(0)) {
    on<IncrementEvent>((event, emit) => emit(state + 1)); //The operator '+' isn't defined for the type 'CounterState'.Try defining the operator '+'.
  }
}
```

Comment: Try writing state.counter ... Not sure but make a try

Answer (score 0):

on((event, emit) => emit(state + 1)); // here you are trying to emit an integer, you have to emit a type of CounterInitial, because you passed CounterInitial(0) in super

Try **on((event, emit) => emit(CounterInitial(state+1)))**